# read text from file and compare the text then store to respective listbox

Tags: vb.net

i have a text file as shown below:

Rice|Food

Coke|Drink

How do i check if it is Food then i will add Rice to food list else add to Drink list?

```
       For Each line In File.ReadAllLines(path)

            Dim temp() As String = line.Split(New Char() {"|"})
            '  Dim tempFood As String() = temp
            '   For Each temp1 In temp

            ' if food then add rice to food list
            ' else add coke to drink list

            If temp.Length = 2 Then

                Dim kind = temp(1).Trim().ToLower()

                If kind = "food" Then
                    lstFood.Items.Add(temp(0).trim())
                ElseIf kind = "beverage" Then
                    lstBeverage.Items.Add(temp(0).trim())
                End If

            End If


            'Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After splitting the line you should check if you have two elements in your array and if the check is positive, then the second element contains the string "food" or "drink". Just an if to choose the correct list of string

```
Dim foodList  = new List(Of String)()
Dim drinkList = new List(Of String)()

For Each line In File.ReadAllLines(path)
    Dim temp() As String = line.Split(New Char() {"|"})
    If temp.Length = 2 Then
       Dim kind = temp(1).Trim().ToLower()
       if kind = "food" Then
          foodList.Add(temp(0).Trim())
       else if kind = "drink" Then
          drinkList.Add(temp(0).Trim())
       else

          MessageBox.Show("Unexpected kind: " & kind)

       End if
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Sorry, i have 1 more question , how about if the content of the file to be read is not following the right format, prompt error message?

Comment: It depends on your "business rules". You could prompt and abort the work or just ignore the bad line and continue. The professional approach is to write a log message in a file and show that file to your user at the end of the loop.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice. But what i mean is to check the file format is it in Rice|Food format? if not then show error message.

Comment: Inside the internal if else if add another else with your error message

Comment: Please be more precise. What is not working? What is your file with the bad input?

Comment: The text file format should look like this -> Chinese Tea|Beverage, if only Chinese Tea then it will prompt error message. I tried put the error message at external if else, it shows error message but still display the result for the next line if the format is correct. Should i just add Close() after error message prompted?

Comment: If this code is inside a Function or a Sub and you don't want to execute any code after the loop then display the error message and add a Return statement, otherwise, you could use the keyword Exit For to break the foreach loop and continue with code outside the loop ([For Each  ... Next statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx))